# Questions that don't need an answer

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Sometimes the original poster asks for proof verification, and when the proof is flawless, people comment with something along the lines of "it's fine". The question is answered from the point of view of the asker, but it will still appear as unanswered for the site (and will pop up as such in search results).

Sometimes a very short comment is enough: the comment is upvoted several times, the asker writes another comment along the lines of "oh I see, thanks" and the question is abandoned, still unanswered.

What is supposed to be done in these cases ?

Comment: If you ask specifically about proof verification/solution verification questions, then this is very probably a duplicate. Did you look at the posts tagged ([meta-tag:solution-verification]) on meta?

Comment: For example, these posts look rather similar: [What to do with a “check/simplify my proof” type question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/what-to-do-with-a-check-simplify-my-prooftype-question), 
[How to answer proof-verification questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-answer-proof-verification-questions)
and [Do proof verification questions fit the website- evade duplicate tag - sometimes answer for them is just 'yes'](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21537),

Comment: It is probably also worth to mention [this suggestion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12867) that once a proof verification question has received sufficient feedback, it can be closed as a duplicate of a question asking for any proof of the result (not only for checking a particular proof). This suggestion received some support (it is currently at +6).